# Linking only vertical offset of two scrollviewers

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, scrollviewer

I have a scrollview with a big grid containing two smaller grids. the grids are supposed to scroll together vertically, but only the right grid should scroll horizontally. This is because the information in the left grid is needed as a reference while the right grid can contain 100+ columns.

I have already tried putting the grids in separate scrollviews and linking them with an eventhandler. But I didn't find any code to do this in a Windows 8.1 application.

Is there any way to do this for WinRT apps?

[image: 2 grids in 1 scrollview]

Comment: Note that for large numbers of rows/columns - you should really try to use virtualization as much as possible - e.g. by using a default `ListView` control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should nest the `ScrollViewers`. Something like this:

```
<Grid
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="700"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">1</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer
                Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                ZoomMode="Disabled">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,50,10" FontSize="24">A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. A very long text. </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried this, but when you scroll down in the right scrollviewer, it doesn't show all the data, just the data that initially fits in the scrollviewer/grid. It's not really scrollable since vertical scroll needs to be disabled to make this work.

Comment: So it looks like this, while there should be those green squares for each textbox http://tinypic.com/r/2hdnmds/8

Comment: update: this works, i just had to change the height of the scrollviewer to fix the aforementioned problem. Thank you!