# XAML GridView in GridView with different orientation

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

(Title edited)

How to do this with XAML?
Horizontal Width is fixed and must be scrollable.

Maybe GridView or another control like ItemsControl or StackPanel.

[image]

Comment: I found answer and it works!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812456/linking-only-vertical-offset-of-two-scrollviewers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple working example: [Linking only vertical offset of two scrollviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812456/linking-only-vertical-offset-of-two-scrollviewers)

And I found advanced example in 5th sample of the "XAML input and manipulations - advanced concepts": https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-input-and-manipulation-44125241

Answer (score 3):

You use **ListView** only when you need to have the elements in vertical direction otherwise **GridView** presents all what you need. It presents the items in the horizontal direction.

The most of the functioning of the both is same.

Comment: @Seema_Soam thank you, but the problem not solved yet. Even if I use GridView, i cannot find example for the illustrated sample

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can have grid with two cells. In left cell will be scrollviewer with stackpanel, in second cell will be scrollviewer with wrappanel with vertical orientation.

If you need to databinnd to some itemssource, use itemscontrols with custom ItemsPanelTemplate - stackpanel, wrappanel, uniform grid, canvas, or whatever panel you need.

EDIT: sample code using two cell with ListView and IntemsControl, each in its own scrollviewer:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="StudentsListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="#484" Height="90"  Width="200">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Markings}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Background="#888" Height="90" Width="90" Margin="5">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" FontSize="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>


    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Students = Enumerable.Range(0, 25)
            .Select(i => new Student
            {
                Name = "Student " + i,
                Markings = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(j => (j + i) % 5 + 1).ToList()
            }).ToList();
    }

    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Markings { get; set; }
}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but if I want to scrolling first vertical stackpanel... What about second cell? Will it be scrolling with first cell together? Vice versa.

Comment: I dont quite get it. You will have two scrollviewers, each is scrolled separatelly, depending on where is your mouse cursor. Do you need some extra behaviour, like when you are scrolling first celld lost and you got to the end, then second cell should start scrolling?

Comment: No, can you image, what we have list of students, first cell of grid with everyday marks in second cell of grid? Yes it simple to imagine, but I cannot code it in XAML.

Comment: It that case it is very simple. Use listview in first cell and gridview in second cell.

Comment: Please, see the picture of my realization: http://tinypic.com/r/24wyidj/8 Blue zone must scrolling with orange zone. But orange zone may have 30 days and this table of marks cannot fit in screen, therefore orange zone must be scrollable, but blue zone must be fixed

Comment: I understand now. basically you need kind of datagrid with fixed row readers ala excel. maybe you should look for such 3rd party datagrid. however I have edited my sample.

Comment: Yeah, my sample is looks like your now... Question is not easy I think

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work by putting the entire row into the datatemplate and use grid columns to set the width:

```
    <ListView Width="500" Height="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" Grid.Column="1"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: As example you may see it in Excel for windows phone

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted. If you want them all to scroll at the same time, there are plenty of examples of that on SO.